# Is it possible to assign a key press code to the press on an Android button?

Tags: android

I have been working on passing an edit text value to a string so I can upload the input to my database, but after a lot of time working I have figured out how to do this by pressing enter on the keyboard. I also have a button for uploading the string and I want to have only the button involved, so the upload button will be enter also.

Here is my button:

```
    submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            public void onClick(View v) {

                postData();
            }

        });
```

Here is the key press enter command:

```
    enter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
              public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                  name = enter.getText().toString();
                  return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
            });
```

Here is where I am using the converted string called name:

```
     nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", name));
```

So I want to get rid of the need for the user to press enter before pressing the submit button, so pressing upload will take care of the enter key press code. I tried creating a method to simulate this being pressed but it didn't work, and researching didn't show me a possible way to assign a key press to a button on click.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Why can't you get the EditText value when you click a button on the screen? It's no different than getting it on your Enter key press.

Comment: I tried this, I put this:

name = enter.getText().toString();

into the submit button but some reason the value is never passed to name as it submits nothing, perhaps I am coding this wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this to perform press button

```
      enter.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
              public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                  name = enter.getText().toString();
                 submit.performclick();
                 return true;
                }
                return false;
              }
            });
```

Comment: That worked perfectly!!!! I will just have a text display informing the user to press enter instead of having the upload button displayed now!

Many thanks!!!!!!!